# How to hide the expand/collapse control in QTreeView?

Tags: qt4, qtreeview

When using QTreeView to display a multi-column list, where the rows have no children and the underlying model is QAbstractTableModel, how does one hide the expand/collapse control?

Answer (score 0):

In PyQt4 this works, but I'm not sure if this is the correct way to do it.

```
def rowCount(self, parent):
    if parent.row() < 0:
        return self.number_of_rows
    return 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to override model's hasChildren() to always return false, rowCount() to always return 0, or both